# Worklight adapter authentication using different authenticator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

This is a generalization of my scenario:
the user of a client app, when challenged for security, could choice to authenticate using more than one method, each one different as parameters (and backend systems to be called, in a more complex scenario).

for example:
- choice A using (id, pwd)
- choice B using (name, cellnum, token)
- choice C using (platenumber)

I'm thinking about a possible first solution where define different "submitAuthentication"-like backend procedures, each one with different signature,  that the client calls based on the user's choice.

A possible second solution (really I don't like), to have a single "submitAuthentication"-like backend procedure where first parameters determines the kind of the choice, and following parameters will be mapped on the expected ones.

Is there some guidelines in order to realize that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish utilizing multiple inputs for authentication. I would suggest looking over the authentication presentations and accompanying samples provided by Worklight:

Authentication Concepts:
[http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_01_Authentication_concepts.pdf](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08%5f01%5fAuthentication%5fconcepts.pdf)

Form Based Authentication:
[http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_02_Form_based_authentication.pdf](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08%5f02%5fForm%5fbased%5fauthentication.pdf)

Adapter Based Authentication:
[http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_03_Adapter_based_authentication.pdf](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08%5f03%5fAdapter%5fbased%5fauthentication.pdf)

Custom Authenticator and Login Module:
[http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_04_Custom_Authenticator_and_Login_Module.pdf](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08%5f04%5fCustom%5fAuthenticator%5fand%5fLogin%5fModule.pdf)

As I  stated looking at your above scenario you could take many routes to accomplish this. I would say your decisions would mostly be based around what design the login would have on the client side. You could have something as simple as having the user choose what kind of login credentials they want to use and have the different situations handled in your challenge handler.

Comment: Jaalger, thanks for your answer.
Yes I know ref you cited: my point is to create different authenticator choices but only one challenge round-trip.
In effect we can think about the scenario where the user can choice -in the middle of the challenge- the kind of credential to use: here the client logic should interact (how is the best way? this is the doubt) to submit data to wl server.

Comment: I am still a little confused with what the issue is. For example in adapter based auth you could write client side logic inside the challenge handler to decide what data to pass into submitAdapterAuthentication call. You could even handle the data on the server side adapter procedure to check what kind of authentication data is being passed and handle it appropriately. Is there a problem with these methods? Do you have a specific issue you are running into?

Comment: yes, this is perfectly the scenario that I tried to describe above: question is what is the best sw design? If I'm not wrong your suggestion fit with the second solution I've put into the question. Simply I'm wondering if could be better to avoid the server side if.. if.. in order to discriminate among backend A or B or C. Maybe better to leave this logic on client side and provide directly different submitAuthA, submitAuthB etc on wlserver side. Hope I clarified better :-) thanks anyway.